# OCI-22053: erro de overflow - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em `MVC` com `C#`.
Eu fiz um método que faz um select no meu banco [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) e com o valor retornado eu preencho um `DataTable`.
Porém ele retorna um erro no momento em que executo o "`dataAdapter.Fill(resultado)`" retornando o erro:

> **OCI-22053: erro de overflow**.

Alguém sabe me dizer o motivo deste erro?

Segue código do método:

```
public DataTable ResgataArquivos()
{
    var resultado = new DataTable();

    myConnection.ConectarBanco(modelLogin);

    var query = "SELECT * FROM ARQUIVO";

    var command = new OracleCommand(query, myConnection.connection);
    var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command); 
    dataAdapter.Fill(resultado);

    myConnection.FecharConexaoBanco();

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Matheus, chegou a fazer um teste limitando quantidade de resultados? (WHERE ROWNUM <= qtd_linhas);

Comment: Não. Mas essa minha tabela só tem 1 registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dei uma pesquisada aqui sobre esse erro e na maioria dos casos o problema era por causa de alguma coluna que era `NUMBER(N,D)` ocorrendo um erro na conversão desses valores, pode acontecer de ser outros campos também que ultrapassaram o limite na hora da conversão portanto dê uma olhada nos seus dados que estão inseridos.

Experimenta dar um `TRUNC` caso você tiver alguma coluna desse tipo.

```
"SELECT TRUNC(VALOR,2) FROM Arquivo"
```

Pessoas com esse mesmo problema: [1](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/308675-resolvido-oci-22053-erro-de-overflow/), [2](http://glufke.net/oracle/viewtopic.php?t=7862) e [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688645/getting-overflow-error-when-executing-pl-sql-query).

Comment: É isso mesmo Maicon! Eu tinha um campo que tinha muitas casas decimais, e não era pra estar. Corrigi o campo e deu certo. Obrigado!